# Can I make one toolbar for all view controllers?

Tags: ios, toolbar

I need to create toolbar with one button in all view controllers. Try to create it in storyboard (add button to Navigation Controller). But nothing. Try to create it in appdelegate, and cant too.

I found this in the manual:

> **Displaying a Navigation Toolbar**
>
> A navigation controller object manages an optional toolbar in its view hierarchy. When displayed, this toolbar obtains its current set of items from the toolbarItems property of the active view controller. When the active view controller changes, the navigation controller updates the toolbar items to match the new view controller, animating the new items into position when appropriate.

Its realy create new toolbar to all new view controllers? I must add my button manualy to all controllers?

Comment: where and what's the purpose of this toolbar?

Comment: I need a help button on all screens

Answer (score -1):

You can create your toolbar in a navigation controller and then in all your view controller in the viewDidLoad()

```
self.toolbarItems = self.navigationController!.toolbarItems
```

But the actions related to the UIBarButtonItems in your toolbar will be define into your navigation controller only.